# How to use CASE inside HAVING COUNT() in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, case, hql, having

I have tested the following SQL query in PostgreSQL client console, which works fine:

```
SELECT document_url FROM signature_transaction WHERE app_id = 2 GROUP BY document_url HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN response_delivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(id);
```

Then I tried to do the same thing in the Java code, using a NamedQuery like this:

```
SELECT t.documentUrl FROM SignatureTransaction t WHERE t.appId = :appId GROUP BY t.documentUrl HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t.responseDelivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t.id)
```

But I received the following error when deploying the application:

```
ERROR [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 86) HHH000177: 
Error in named query: SignatureTransaction.findUrlOfDeliveredDocuments: 
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: responseDelivered near line 1, column 133 
[SELECT t.documentUrl FROM org.app.model.SignatureTransaction t WHERE t.appId = :appId GROUP BY t.documentUrl HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN responseDelivered THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(t.id)]
```

I tried to use all this names inside the COUNT(), none worked:

- `responseDelivered`
- `t.responseDelivered`
- `response_delivered`
- `org.app.model.SignatureTransaction.responseDelivered`

What is the right way to write this HQL?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check that SignatureTransaction entity has responseDelivered field and it's name set correctly. Note HSQL not see to name column of table just name field in entity, it's important.

Comment: The field declaration is `@Column(name = "response_delivered") private boolean responseDelivered;`, but it's on a super class, called Transaction.

Comment: I've just tried `org.app.model.Transaction.responseDelivered` on the CASE, but got same error.